# GNU Octave Code Equivalent in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, matlab, octave

I have some GNU octave/Matlab code that I would like to translate into C or C++. I can handle most of this translation but I don't know what the line `x1=0:1:pts-1;`would translate to in C code. If i understand correctly it is a Range type in Octave but i'm not sure what data type in C or C++ would support that same functionality.
The Full script is:

```
pkg load signal
fs = 48000;
fc=18300;
rlen=10;
ppiv=100;
beta=9.0;
apof=0.9;
apobeta=0.7;

pts = ppiv*rlen+1;

x1=0:1:pts-1;%this line here!!!!

x2=rlen*2*(x1-(pts-1)/2 +0.00001)/(pts-1); % and the the usage of x1 in this line
x3=pi*fc/fs*x2;
h=sin(x3)./x3;
w=kaiser(pts,beta);
g=w.*h;

aw = 1-apof*kaiser(pts,apobeta);
g=aw.*g;
g=g/max(g);



figure(1);
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(x2/2,g);
axis([-rlen/2 rlen/2 -0.2 2.0002]);
%xlabel(“Time in Sampling Intervals”);
%title(‘Bandlimited Impulse’);
subplot(1,2,2);
zpad=20;
g2=[g;zeros((zpad-1)*pts,1)];
wspec=abs(fft(g2));
wspec=max(wspec/max(wspec),0.00001);
fmax=60000;
rng = round(rlen*zpad*fmax/fs);
xidx = 0:1:rng;
semilogy(fmax/1000*xidx/rng,wspec(1:(rng+1)));
%xlabel(‘Frequency in kHz’);
%title(‘amplitude spectrum’);
grid;

hold;
plot([20 20],[0.00001,1]);
plot([fs/1000-20 fs/1000-20], [0.00001 1]);
plot([fs/1000 fs/1000], [0.00001 1]);
hold off;
```

So what i am looking for Is either a code snippet or some resource of how to deal with this conversion.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When I convert Matlab code into C++, I prefer based my work on a numerical framework and I used Boost Matrix in several project but you have a lot of choice [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#C.2B.2B), for the fft look at KISS FTT for example and for [plotting](https://code.google.com/p/matplotpp/)

Comment: if you are converting your Octave code to C++, are you using Octave's c++ library? It will make things much easier because you have constructors for this type of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x1 is an array (or if you prefer, a matrix) holding values 0,1,2,3,...,(pts-1).

So you could generate it in C with something like:

```
int a[500];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  a[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: so the next line `x2=rlen*2*(x1-(pts-1)/2 +0.00001)/(pts-1);` would also be calculated using a loop where `x2` would be an array and i would do something like `x2[i] = ...x1[i]...`?

Comment: yes, that's just scalar multiplication and addition, so you can get x2 (which will also be an array) using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are converting from Octave code, it makes a lot of sense to use Octave's C++ library. They can see its [doxygen docs](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/index.html) online.

For your specific case you can use the [`octave_range`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d5/da7/classoctave__range.html) class:

```
#include "ov-range.h"
octave_range x (0, pts -1, 1);
```

Note that this would only be a range, just like in Octave. If you then want a matrix out of it, you can do:

```
Matrix mx = x.matrix_value ();
```

If this confuses you, converting the range to a matrix, see how it's actually done in Octave. Create a range and check its size in memory. Then compare with the matrix created from it:

```
octave-cli-3.8.1> x = 0:1:10000;
octave-cli-3.8.1> whos x
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  ===== 
        x           1x10001                     24  double

Total is 10001 elements using 24 bytes

octave-cli-3.8.1> x = [0:1:10000];
octave-cli-3.8.1> whos x
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  ===== 
        x           1x10001                  80008  double

Total is 10001 elements using 80008 bytes
```